# How to pass url to open up in webview from a notification in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, webview

So far in my delegate I have been able to successfully get the URL from a notification, where I am having issues is how to pass the url to my viewcontroller.swift to open the url in webview. I have tried several examples from stack but they seem to not work with swift 4.2. Can anyone help me? Sorry I am new to swift.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let data = userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]

    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .background {
        // background
        print("==== Active Running ====")
        if let aps = data["aps"] {
            let url = aps["url"]
        }
    }
    else if state == .inactive {
        // inactive
        print("==== Inactive Running ====")
        if let aps = data["aps"] {
            let url = aps["url"]
        }
    }
    else if state == .active {
        // foreground
        print("==== Foreground Running ====")
        if let aps = data["aps"] {
            let url = aps["url"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a global variable and replace your existing url with new one. Now reloaded your page that's it.

Comment: Could you throw me an example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to initialize that view controller from scratch you can just do so in your Appdelegate, where you get your URL by:

```
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerID") as! YourViewController
        vc.url = url
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Also in `YourViewController` file, set your url like:

```
var url = "" {
    didSet {
       //trigger your webView to start loading, you can also do it at viewDidAppear maybe.
       //example:
       let url = URL(string: url)
       let request = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error at `YourViewController` Use of undeclared type 'YourViewController'. Should it be `UIViewController`?

Comment: You should replace YourViewController, with the viewcontroller you want to set the webView in. What is the name of your view controller? I used YourViewController as reference.

Comment: Im sorry I am very new to swift. So I think it's name is webView? `@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!`. Maybe `UIViewController`?